# Clickable elements inside an image - web board game

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

I'm trying to implement a board game with React, and I'm strugling in finding a way to "convert" the board squares on the UI (on the image) to data.

Is there any way to assign some sort id's to the squares on the attached image, so when the user clicks on a square, I get the id of the square?

I wanna know when the user has clicked on a certain square inside the image.

PS.I don't have an .svg image. Only a .png file..

[image]

Comment: What about to use the `area` tag? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Comment: Sounds interesting! I'm gonna try that out. Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) and [`<area>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) tags like below. You can add more `<area>` tags for each "button" and give it an action. You'll have to play around with the `coords` a bit.

```js
function doSomething() {
  console.log("click");
}

function doSomething2() {
  console.log("click2");
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/suFoO.jpg" width="imgwidth" height="imgheight" alt="alttext" usemap="#mapname">

<map name="mapname">
    <area shape="rect" coords="40,10,130,130" alt="alttext" onclick="doSomething()">
    <area shape="rect" coords="130,10,250,130" alt="alttext" onclick="doSomething2()">
</map>
```

Comment: @YousefM Your welcome. I'm always glad to help. Good luck with your project!